# Browse Directories for save location

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need code that will allow the user to do the following:

1. Select a browse button and choose the folder they want to save a file once the exe file at the end of the program runs
2. Display the folder location the user selected in the textbox next to it

Basically this is a save dialog box but since this is a web application and not a web form I can not use the dialog boxes.

Here is the code I have so far, I am thinking its not right so please help me with this!

```
Protected Sub Browse_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Browse.Click
    Dim FilePath As String = ("C:\Users\Public\Documents")
    Dim targetFile As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath)

    If targetFile.Exists Then
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + targetFile.Name)
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", targetFile.Length.ToString)
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Response.WriteFile(targetFile.FullName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you letting them choose a location on the server, or a location on their PC? What 'exe file at the end of the program'?

Comment: They are choosing a location on their pc...something as simple as C:\Temp is fine. And the exe file is just a program that will read all the information from the page

Comment: That would be a security hole. Just feed them the file, and let their browser decide where to save it.

Comment: so I would choose the file location. Can you show me what that would look like in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they said, you can't do exactly what you want to due to security.  But you can rely on a asp.net file upload control.

[link](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/)

Comment: Can you show me that in code? I know how to put the upload control on my form but how can I make it so I can choose the location I will later save information to?

Comment: You cannot save files to the client's machine from the web browser because it has security implications. Could you imagine if you browsed to a site and they got access to store files on your machine?  Now you can store those files on the web server or any shares the web app has access too.